Detect client side navigaton with next/navigation (Next 13+)
Simple question, I need to detect when users navigate on the app.
Route changes occur with the <Link> attribute using react/link.
I have a context that needs to listen for any navigation in order to add a parameter to the router.
My context currently uses next/navigation to update the parameter like this :
useEffect(() => {
    router.push(`?....`)
}, [currentLanguage])

I have tried to add router in my use effect deps but it's not being triggered when route changes.

I'm not sure about it being best practice, but you can add pathname as a dependency
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation'

const pathname = usePathname()

useEffect(() => {
    router.push(`?....`)
}, [currentLanguage, pathname])


https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router#router-events
